# Order by count rows from another table

Tags: php, sql

I am asking this question after a lot of research on google and also seen questions on StackOverflow but I don't understand what they say. It's too difficult!
I have two tables First named: `Private_Messages` And Second: `Friends`
All I have to do is sort the list of friends by messages.

```
Friends
1. id
2. user_one
3. user_two      


Private Messages
1. msg_from
2. msg_two
```

And I am listing them without any order with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_one='$Id' OR user_two='$Id'
```

Here `$Id` is the logged user

This thing I get with this query:

1. Angel
2. Hero
3. Iron Man

But I want this:

1. Iron Man
2. Hero
3. Angel

Because the logged in user has talked too much with Iron Man

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Sort by messages ?= sort alphabetically (or sort by what exactly). Also, the structure of your tables is not clear. Don't hesitate on looking thru the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or in 
the [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to be sure about how to ask questions. 
Remember to add all code (the CREATE TABLE sentences), the error logs and everything in your question (as plain text), so we can provide better help. :)

Comment: Show us example of current data and desired result

Comment: I have added the desired result, I don't even know how I start creating this Thing :(

Comment: @Alfabravo Like in facebook the friends list is sort by Messages

Comment: what is the relation (foreign key) between friends and private messages tables?